# how to use pagination with sinatra for string that is connected to a mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, pagination, sinatra

I am looking to put in pagination into my sinatra web application, The purpose of the web app is pretty much a CRUD application that is connected to a mongo database. 
On the pages that I want to implement pagination there are a huge amount of list elements as seen in the link below. I was looking to have 20 records per page so I and then the usual pagination on the bottom of the page to keep track of the number of pages

The link to the list is here
http://postimg.org/image/526l1klvj/
(unable to post image because reputation is too low)

Comment: What datamapper do you use, and what have you tried to build pagination?

Comment: currently I'm using mongoid for connection

Answer (score 0):

Below code snippet is not tested and relies on relevant assumptions, change the values as per need

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'mongo'
require 'json/ext' # required for .to_json

include Mongo

configure do
  conn = MongoClient.new("localhost", 27017)
  set :mongo_connection, conn
  set :mongo_db, conn.db('test')
end

get '/api/?' do
  offset = params[:offset].nil? 0 : params[:offset]
  limit = params[:limit].nil? 5 : params[:limit]
  settings.mongo_db['test'].find.skip(offset).limit(count).to_a.to_json
end
```

Source

http://recipes.sinatrarb.com/p/databases/mongo